# Why my 7-year-old dog barks when I leave home while when my parents leave he doesn’t bark?

Tags: dogs, health, training, safety, feeding

I own a 7-year-old Jack Russell and since he was a puppy he started to bark every time I was leaving; it may seem like “usual” behaviour but it gets strange because when my parents or my sister also leave he doesn’t bark. Can someone explain to me why he has this behaviour?

I state that my mother feeds him and walks him out and we don’t spend much time together.

Comment: I am afraid that this question cannot be properly answered by a stranger from the internet. The main reason for that is "what kind of barking are we talking about?". If you could "read" the barking correctly, you would not be asking a question here. But since you ask the question here, it means that you cannot "read" the barking, so we cannot have the good understanding of the situation, in order to really help. *Please try to find a specialist in your area, who would come to your home and watch your dog (and your family) and who could give you proper and useful advice.*

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Maybe you can add a video or audio data to let us hear the barking? But truly answers will be some kind of guessing.

Answer (score 2):

My dog does a similar thing, but only ever to strangers.

The only way to tell would be to see if your dog is using an "angry" bark, which would be deep and followed by a growl, if it is a "playful" bark, it will be higher and sounds a bit like "yip yip yip!" Since you have a Jack russell, angry barks will be lighter than what a larger dog would have, but you should still be able to tell.

The behavior most likely comes from being very loyal to a certain person in your family, and therefore barks when that person is not present.

NOTE: my dog barks just to hear himself make noise, it is not related to your situation.